# Regular Expression matching empty string before a character in c#

Tags: c#, regex, regular-language

I am trying to match a string containing nothing before a character.

Consider the following lines:

```
'this is a valid line
  'this is also a valid line
 Any string ' this is an invalid line
```

I Need a regular expression that matches the first two line and does not match third line.

Basic regex tried was `'.*` but it matches all the three lines:

So need a regex that does not match a non empty string before `'`

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285733/327083

Comment: https://regex101.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

perhaps try anchor at the beginning... `^\s*'.*`

Comment: Please don’t answer [these kind of questions](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285733/should-give-me-a-regex-that-does-x-questions-be-closed).

Comment: This is partally  working .
It does not include the intial spaces.

Comment: @Jaskaran even after my edit?

Comment: Yea working for me now .....Thanks a lot!